# How to do "like" on dictionary key?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I do a "like" to find a dictionary key?  I'm currently doing:

```
mydict.ContainsKey(keyName);
```

But some keyNames have an additional word appended (separated by a space), I'd like to do a "like" or .StartsWith().  The comparisons will look like this:

```
"key1" == "key1"  //match
"key1" == "key1 someword" //partial match
```

I need to match in both cases.

Comment: what do you want returned? The key values or if they exist?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use LINQ to do this.

Here are two examples:

`bool anyStartsWith = mydict.Keys.Any(k => k.StartsWith("key1"))`

`bool anyContains = mydict.Keys.Any(k => k.Contains("key1"))`

It is worth pointing out that this method will have worse performance than the .ContainsKey method, but depending on your needs, the performance hit will not be noticable.

Answer (score 4):

```
mydict.Keys.Any(k => k.StartsWith("key1"));
```

While enumerating over the `Keys` you will lose the performance benefits of a dictionary:

```
mydict.ContainsKey(someKey); // O(1)
mydict.Keys.Any(k => k.StartsWith("key1")); // O(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the `.Contains()` method of the string and not the dictionary you'll get what you want.

```
var matchingKeys = mydict.Keys.Where(x => x.Contains("key1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = (from key mydict.keys where key.contains(keyName) select key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Keys member of the dictionary can be manipulated to check for presence with more complicated semantics than equality. It need not be a LINQ extension method check, but that is likely the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the keys themselves and not a true/false you can do:

```
string match = "key1";

    var matches = from k in mydict
                      where k.Key.Contains(match)
                      select new
                      {
                          k.Key
                      };
```

Answer (score 0):

For matching and retrieving keys "like" you could use these extensions.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool HasKeyLike<T>(this Dictionary<string, T> collection, string value)
    {
        var keysLikeCount = collection.Keys.Count(x => x.ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower()));
        return keysLikeCount > 0;
    }

    public static List<string> GetKeysLike<T>(this Dictionary<string, T> collection, string value)
    {
        return collection.Keys.Select(x => x.ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
}
```